# The flip graph of triangulations

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

A polygon $P_k$ divided by $k-2$ diagonals into triangles is called a polygonal triangulation. These are the vertices of the triangulation graph $\mathcal P_k$. Two vertices are connected by an edge if one triangulation is obtained from another by the *diagonal flip*, i.e. we take two triangles of the triangulation that share a side, and in their union (where that side is a diagonal), replace that diagonal by the other diagonal. Sleator, Tarjan, and Thurston proved that the diameter of the
triangulation graph ${\mathcal P}_k$ is bounded above by $2k-10$. Hence the problem of finding a shortest path in that graph between two triangulations is in NP.

**Question 1.**  Is it in P?

**Question 2.**  What is known about the complexity of finding the shortest path in the triangulation graph of other surfaces?

**Update.**  I have posted a followup [question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47035/poincare-conjecture-and-the-graph-of-triangulations)

Comment: Could you clarify why finding the shortest path between two triangulations is in NP?  It doesn't seem obvious to me.  

Comment: @Hugh: The witness is a sequence of triangulations of length $O(k)$. The size of this witness is $O(k^2)$.

Comment: But that witness doesn't witness that it's the shortest.  Or am I missing something?


Comment: Hmm, you are right! But it seems that I was right too because both Joseph and David seem to think so. It could be some standard CS idea (which I cannot remember now).  

Comment: Both Joseph's and David's answers helped a lot, but I cannot accept both. Since Joseph's answer came first, I will accept it. I will make the update another question.   

Comment: Hey Mark, could you clarify what you mean by the triangulation graph of a surface? I believe you mean the graph consisting with vertices given by triangulations up to isotopy, and edges given by flips. Thus, one needs to fix the number of vertices. If so, then this graph is infinite diameter except for a few special cases, since it is q.i. to the mapping class group of the surface. But they you might mean only up to homeomorphism, in which case it is be finite diameter. However, this is not quite analogous to the flip graph of a polygon, but would allow symmetries of the polygon. 

Comment: Hello Ian, thanks! I guess I meant "isometry". I did not know that it is q.i. to the mapping class group. So the problem then is equivalent to finding a geodesic (or a quasi-geodesic path) in the MCG? 

Comment: A comment on the NP question: to get a decision problem (and therefore stand a chance of being in NP) you usually ask "is there a solution of length at most $k$?"  You can then find the minimum $k$ by binary search.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to add a little to Joseph's nice answer, for part 1 of your question: although the problem of computing the flip distance in polynomial time is wide open for triangulations of convex polygons, it can be solved in polynomial time for triangulations of certain highly nonconvex point sets (such as the intersection of the integer lattice with a convex set): see my paper "Happy Endings for Flip Graphs", SoCG 2007 and [JoCG 2010](https://doi.org/10.20382/jocg.v1i1a2).

Comment: Great paper title! :-)

Comment: Re connections to Poincaré: sorry, that doesn't sound familiar to me.

Comment: I moved the update to a new question. Perhaps some geometers here know the answer. 

Comment: @Mark-Sapir, could you edit your current question to also include a pointer to your updated new question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47035/poincare-conjecture-and-the-graph-of-triangulations so that someone reading this question can find the forward link to MO question 47035 right at the top?  I already noted that the new question has a link pointing back to this question.  By the way, (+1) very nice question, and very informative answers and references by Eppstein and O'Rourke.

Comment: @sleepless in beantown: See the update. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that JOCG changed their website, the link in the post no longer works - this seems to be the new location: https://jocg.org/index.php/jocg/article/view/2969. (Of course, since full details are given in the answer, the paper can be easily found [in many various places](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%20Eppstein+Happy+endings+for+flip+graphs).)

Comment: Link replaced with doi (which was also broken in the same way, but is now working again).

Answer (score 8):

I believe your two questions are not directly related. As far as I know, **Question 1** is open.

[**Edit.** I answered the 2nd question under the interpretation that "the triangulation graph of other surfaces" meant the graph of the surface triangulation, which, as Agol pointed out,
is likely not what Mark meant.  Rather he meant the flip graph, which is the focus of the 1st
question.  So the below does not answer the intended question. (The flip graph does not always
make sense on a surface.)]

Let me address **Question 2**.  For a long time, the fastest algorithm for finding the shortest path
on a triangulated 2-manifold was the 1996 Chen and Han algorithm, which runs in $O(n^2)$ time for
a surface of $n$ vertices. Here is an example from an implemention of mine with students
of this algorithm,
showing the shortest paths from one point to all the vertices of a convex polyhedron:

[image]

This and other algorithms are described in
*[Geometric Folding Algorithms: Linkages, Origami, Polyhedra](http://www.gfalop.org/)*, Section 24.2.

There was effort over many years toward improving the time complexity in the special case of surfaces of convex polyhedra,
which was finally cracked by
Schreiber and Sharir in their remarkable paper,

> Schreiber, Yevgeny, and Micha Sharir. "An optimal-time algorithm for shortest paths on a convex polytope in three dimensions." *Discrete Comput. Geom.*,  Springer, **39** (2008), 500-579; Twentieth Anniversary Volume, 2009. 1-80.
>   ([Here](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1137862) is the earlier conference version.)

They improved the speed to $O(n \log n)$;
the shortest paths are represented implicitly to avoid the $n^2$ complexity of explicit listing.
This time complexity has only been achieved to-date for subclasses of nonconvex surfaces.

Comment: Great! I should have asked earlier: I spent 2 hours trying to find references myself. Thank you! 

Comment: @Mark:  Maybe you are thinking of an old result of Tindell?: If the Poincaré conjecture were false, then there are locally flat noncombinatorial triangulations of $S^n$ for all $n \ge 5$. But now that we know the conjecture is a theorem, we also know that every locally flat triangulation of a topological manifold is also combinatorial.

Comment: Joseph: I did not see your comment before I posted a new question. I know about Tindell's paper. The problem was about computational complexity and it was related to the graph of triangulations. 

Comment: Joseph's comment isn't entirely right. The double suspension of a triangulation of the Poincar'e homology 3-sphere gives a noncombinatorial (but otherwise perfectly nice) triangulation of the 5-sphere, by results of R. Edwards and J. Cannon. And this persists in higher dimensions by additional suspensions.

Comment: @Allan: I defer to you here. I must be misinterpreting Tindell's Theorem 1 from "Noncombinatorial Triangulations and the Poincaré Conjecture."

Comment: I don't understand how this answer is related to Question 2: I thought Mark was asking for the shortest path in the graph of triangulations of a surface, where vertices of the graph are triangulations, and edges are related by flips (of course, the number of tetrahedra of the triangulation must be fixed, unless other Pachner moves are allowed). This seems to have nothing to do with your answer, which appears to be about finding shortest paths in the 1-skeleton of a triangulated surface. But maybe I misinterpreted Mark's question. 

Comment: @Agol: Perhaps it is me who misinterpreted Mark's question.  That is why I said that the two questions were unrelated; they are under my interpretation. But your interpretation makes more sense, that both questions are about the flip graph, not the graph of the surface itself.

Comment: You should un-accept my answer, in light of my likely misinterpretation, and accept David's instead.

Comment: @Joseph: Indeed, thanks to Ian, I understand my mistake now. I will accept David's answer. But thank you for the reference to the book. It is very interesting. 